# 'innerHTML' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have currently this line in my page :

```
<p id="replaced">
    <a id="linkReplace" href="https://www.g2a.com/r/nowyoushare">
        <img src="images/ads.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
    </a>
</p>
```

So adblock detect and block my link and picture:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoLgS.png)

So a created a test script with `JavaScript` but it doesn't work :/

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> 
<script>
    if(document.getElementById('replaced').length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = 'chocolat';
    }
</script>
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you want to try `if(document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML == "")` denoting if there is no HTML inside `<p>` tag.

Comment: thanks, adblock delete the <p> or not ?

Comment: I have no idea if p is deleted. If `<p>` is deleted then you cannot use `document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = 'chocolat';`; instead you need to re-create the `<p>` tag... in such case maybe directly add `<p>chocolat</p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want that if "replaced" is empty so add some content into

If you want to check if the content is empty so use `.innerHTML.length` :

```
if(document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = 'chocolat';
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Empty content case :**

```js
if(document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML.length == 0) {
  document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = 'chocolat';
}
```

```html
<p id="replaced"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to understand what are you ting to achieve..can you explain it better?

BTW..

```
if(document.getElementById('replaced').length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = 'chocolat';
    }
```

Basically you are saying "if the element replaced doesn't exist, replace the content inside of it". How it could possibly work?

**EDIT** after the response from @bezoo

You could write something like that to create the element after checking if it exist.

```
 if(document.getElementById('replaced').length == 0) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.setAttribute("id", "replaced");
        }
```

and then do whatever you want with the innerhtml of the element you just created.

**EDIT2**
I misunderstood..

this code should work

```
if(document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML == "") {
            document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = 'chocolat';
        }
```

Comment: But I want that if "replaced" is empty so add some content into

Answer (score -1):

`getElementById` returns an HTML Element Node. It doesn't have a `length` property, so that property will never be equal to `0`.

If you are trying to test if the element exists, then check that the return value is a true value:

```
if (document.getElementById('replaced'))
```